# How to restyle control to have specific UI in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

here i am giving the image of a control which will show the thumbnail of many images and user can scroll among the images. user can set how many images will show per line. user can set how many rows will show and can databind etc.

[image]

i am new in WPF.so just guide me how can i draw the output like above. thanks

### UPDATE

[image]

[image]

Comment: use ListBox with ItemStyle...

Comment: @Thomas really? With all due respect, you've got 4000+ reputation points which is more than enough to for you to know better... basically you're saying 'this is the work that I want you all to do for me for free so that I don't even have to bother trying to do it myself'. That generally doesn't go down well with users here as you should know already. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: i was looking at this code from this url http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18561/Custom-ListBox-Layout-in-WPF and i guess it is bit similar but still lots of difference in UI & functionality. the image here i given there is area where user can click to navigate in images. so looking for help. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you need to add the Up, Down, which would scroll `ListBox` with images. `ListBox` already contains a `ScrollViewer` with the standard scroll bar. I propose that we should hide the standard scroll bar, and set yourself with navigation buttons.

Functionality of these buttons will refer to the standard `ScrollViewer`. In order to gain access to the `ScrollViewer` in `ListBox`, you must use the function:

```
public static DependencyObject GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject Object)
{
    if (Object is ScrollViewer)
    {
        return Object;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(Object); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Object, i);
        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);

        if (result == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

With the help of `VisualTreeHelper` this function returns an object of type `ScrollViewer`.

*Vertical Up* navigation is as follows:

```
scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - 30);
```

We define a style for the buttons, which will contain a `Path` in the form of arrows. A complete example with comments is below.

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="CustomListboxNavHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomListboxNavHelp"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">

<Window.Resources>      
    <!-- Style for ListBox -->
    <Style x:Key="MyListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />

        <!-- Hidden Scrollbar`s -->
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />

        <!-- DataTemplate for ListBoxItem -->
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="140" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Style for UpButton -->
    <Style x:Key="UpButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Up" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Path x:Name="UpButton" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="20" Height="18" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Gray" Data="F1 M 37.8516,35.625L 34.6849,38.7917L 23.6016,50.2708L 23.6016,39.9792L 37.8516,24.9375L 52.1016,39.9792L 52.1016,50.2708L 41.0182,38.7917L 37.8516,35.625 Z "/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="UpButton" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Style for DownButton -->
    <Style x:Key="DownButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Down" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Path x:Name="DownButton" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="20" Height="18" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Gray" Data="F1 M 37.8516,39.5833L 52.1016,24.9375L 52.1016,35.2292L 37.8516,50.2708L 23.6016,35.2292L 23.6016,24.9375L 37.8516,39.5833 Z "/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="DownButton" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="UpDirection" Style="{StaticResource UpButtonStyle}" Width="40" Height="30" Click="UpDirection_Click" />

        <ListBox Name="MyListBox" Style="{StaticResource MyListBoxStyle}" Width="110" Height="300" />

        <Button Name="DownDirection" Style="{StaticResource DownButtonStyle}" Width="40" Height="30" Click="DownDirection_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<ImagesClass> ImagesCollection = new ObservableCollection<ImagesClass>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImagesCollection.Add(new ImagesClass()
        {
            MyImagePath = "Cover1.png"     // Images must be in resource
        });

        ImagesCollection.Add(new ImagesClass()
        {
            MyImagePath = "Cover2.png"
        });

        ImagesCollection.Add(new ImagesClass()
        {
            MyImagePath = "Cover3.png"
        });

        ImagesCollection.Add(new ImagesClass()
        {
            MyImagePath = "Cover4.png"
        });

        ImagesCollection.Add(new ImagesClass()
        {
            MyImagePath = "Cover5.png"
        });

        ImagesCollection.Add(new ImagesClass()
        {
            MyImagePath = "Cover6.png"
        });

        MyListBox.ItemsSource = ImagesCollection;
    }

    private void UpDirection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationInScrollViewer(MyListBox, "Up", 40);
    }

    private void DownDirection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationInScrollViewer(MyListBox, "Down", 40);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Vertical navigation for ListBox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="myListbox">ListBox</param>
    /// <param name="direction">Direction for scrolling</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Offset</param>
    private void NavigationInScrollViewer(ListBox myListbox, string direction, int offset) 
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(MyListBox) as ScrollViewer;

        if (direction == "Up") 
        {
            if (scrollViewer != null)
            {
                scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - offset);
            }
        }

        if (direction == "Down") 
        {                
            if (scrollViewer != null)
            {
                scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + offset);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get ScrollViewer from Control
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Object">Dependency object</param>
    /// <returns>ScrollViewer control</returns>
    public static DependencyObject GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject Object)
    {
        if (Object is ScrollViewer)
        {
            return Object;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(Object); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Object, i);
            var result = GetScrollViewer(child);

            if (result == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Class contain paths to images
/// </summary>
public class ImagesClass
{
    private string myImagePath = null;

    public string MyImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            return myImagePath;
        }

        set
        {
            myImagePath = value;
        }
    }
}
```

`Output`

[image]

**`EDIT:`**

To show multiple images in a single `ListBoxItem`, you need to to correct `ItemTemplate`. I suggest using a `Grid`, since it is a property of `ColumnDefenition` for defining the column number for the item.

Another thing is that you know it is desirable:

- The final number of images displayed in one `ListBoxItem`.
- For a large number of images need to improve the method, since it is more suitable for static display.

Correct `ItemTenplate` like that:

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyImagePathOne}" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="140" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyImagePathTwo}" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="140" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
       </DataTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

`ImageClass`

```
public class ImagesClass
{
    private string myImagePathOne = null;

    public string MyImagePathOne
    {
        get
        {
            return myImagePathOne;
        }

        set
        {
            myImagePathOne = value;
        }
    }

    private string myImagePathTwo = null;

    public string MyImagePathTwo
    {
        get
        {
            return myImagePathTwo;
        }

        set
        {
            myImagePathTwo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Add images to collection:

```
ImagesCollection.Add(new ImagesClass()
{
    MyImagePathOne = "Cover1.png",
    MyImagePathTwo = "Cover2.png"
});

ImagesCollection.Add(new ImagesClass()
{
    MyImagePathOne = "Cover3.png",
    MyImagePathTwo = "Cover4.png"
});

ImagesCollection.Add(new ImagesClass()
{
    MyImagePathOne = "Cover5.png",
    MyImagePathTwo = "Cover6.png"
});
```

`Output`

[image]

If you definitely need to dynamically change the number of images, from in this case, you can do this  - set the collection where the property is set, for example, only a single image. Then, clean it and place it on the set values with an arbitrary number of images.

I think this method is not one hundred percent for this approach. If speed is important, or a large number of images, it is necessary to optimize the method, or come up with another.

**`EDIT 2`**

Up and Down buttons:

```
<Button Name="Up" Width="150" Height="15" Background="#CDE2FF">
    <Button.Content>
        <Polygon Points="3.33,0 6.66,6.66, 0,6.66" Fill="#466690" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>

<Button Name="Down" Width="150" Height="15" Background="#CDE2FF" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <Button.Content>
        <Polygon Points="0,0 3.33,6.66, 6.66,0" Fill="#466690" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

`Output`

[image]

Comment: i am new in wpf...how one need to change in ur code to show two images in same row?

Comment: thanks for updating ur answer. i have update my question please have a look once. thanks

Comment: thanks for answer. as per image i have given the UP/Down button width should be equal to listbox width. u define button width=150 & listbox width=110. so i think that need to be change. anyway great help....cheers :) :)

Comment: i like to ask u a question because i feel u r sound enough in WPF. is there any site which provide huge sample code for wpf only for developing glossy attractive UI. i search google but found none. if u r aware then please give me those url. thanks

Comment: @Thomas: I usually do so. Choose control to fit your needs, then I look for his `Style`, such as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx), then I edit it by his idea. For example, you can install [`MahApps.Metro`](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/), and look at the the new elements, as well as styles. To find a `Path`-icons can recommend a super website - http://modernuiicons.com, there you can find any icon that can be used without problems in the WPF. Also you can read the relevant chapter in the book of Adam Nathan, a very good book.

Comment: Adam Nathan wrote any books on WPF? if yes then what is the title. thanks for answer. :)

Comment: `Adam Nathan. WPF 4 Unleashed` - [link](http://www.amazon.com/WPF-4-Unleashed-Adam-Nathan/dp/0672331195).